# Using SSIS script task to connect to on-premise servers using Self-Hosted IR as a proxy for Azure-SSIS IR in ADF

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect to on-premise rest web-service using SSIS script task , and running it in Azure Data Factory on its SSIS-IR which has a proxy to Self-Hosted IR which eventually connects to on-premise servers.
Is it feasible, any settings is required?
I am following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-proxy-ssis#enable-ssis-packages-to-connect-by-proxy
But it only talks about odbc connection managers, not about a script task , which i wish to persom some rest api calls to web services hosted on premises.
ADF's REST connectors or web activity is not an option here, as the API's are meant to download images, but these out-of-the-box ADF connectors doesn't support non-json responses.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. its a script task. you can do whatever you want there

Comment: The issue is connectivity to on-premise servers not on azure.
I am trying to use my existing SelfHosted-IR as proxy as mentioned in the documentaion above.

Comment: i'm not much of an adf user, but I suspect you can pick where to run the task, just pick selfhoster runtime and run the script task there

Comment: If you want to conncet to a REST API and download images, SSIS really isn't the right tool. Unless you have other very data driven functionality required.

Comment: @PrashantKumar was this resolved? i am also working on similar implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Only components that work for me have been: With the new `ConnectByProxy` or `ExecuteOnProxy` properties, I had to install the stand-alone SSDT on my Visual Studio PC before these properties appeared in only the following components:

- All types of connection manager objects.
- Execute SQL task
- Execute SQL process

Also, a 'source' script component in a data flow task if you add the specific Connection Manager from the edit menu of the script component.

I have not been able to access the on-premise data source from a SQL task component.